# How to obtain single value from multiple threads (array summation row by row) - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix

I am trying to upgrade the library of mine for some geophysics computations. I created the example for demonstration. I would like to use multiple threads to do so. Let's say i want to sum the matrix elements in my own structure. The summation is computed row by row:

Here is some source code with commentary

HEADER:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>  /* rand */
#include <thread>   /* multithread library */
                    /* std::thread::hardware_concurrency() from  c++ : --stdc=c++11 */
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_T       4
```

STRUCTURE:

```
struct ARRAY {
    /* Matrix with  n-rows, m-cols */
    double** mtrx;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
};
```

CREATE AND DELETE:

```
ARRAY create_array (unsigned int r,unsigned int c ){
    struct ARRAY mtrx;
    double** elem;

    elem = new double*[r];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<r; i++){
        elem[i] = new double[c];
    };

    mtrx.mtrx = elem;
    mtrx.rows = r;
    mtrx.cols = c;

    return mtrx;
};

void delete_array ( struct ARRAY& mtrx){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mtrx.rows; ++i){
            delete mtrx.mtrx[i];
            mtrx.mtrx[i] = NULL;
    };
    delete mtrx.mtrx;
};
```

Filling some random values:

```
void rand_array ( struct ARRAY& mtrx){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mtrx.rows; i++){
        for( unsigned int j = 0; j < mtrx.cols; j++){
            mtrx.mtrx[i][j] = rand() % 1000; /* rand number from 0-1000; */
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the main problem (i am aware that filling the matrix with random values can be parallelized too).

Sum up ( dummy function )

```
inline double sum_array_line ( double* arr_line, unsigned int ncols ){
    double s = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ncols; i++){
        s += arr_line[i];
    }
    return s;
};
```

And in the end the final one:

```
double sum_array_mt ( struct ARRAY mtrx ){
    thread t[NUM_T];

    double sum__ = 0.0;

    unsigned int i = 0 ;
    while ( i < mtrx.rows ){
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < NUM_T; j++){
            t[j] = thread(sum_array_line, mtrx.mtrx[i++], mtrx.cols );
        }

        for (unsigned int j = 0 ; j < NUM_T; j++){
            t[j].join();
        }
    }
    return sum__;
}
```

The main problem is i have no idea how to pass the value obtained from single thread to sum__ . Can anyone give me a hint please?

And of course the main function:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[]){

    ARRAY mat = create_array(100, 100);
    rand_array( mat );
    double sum_par = sum_array_mt( mat );
    cout << "The sum of matrix is: " << sum_par << endl;

    delete_array( mat );

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for providing the solution. If it works i can easily modify it for my library. Thanks.

Comment: Make your title describe the question/problem please.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`sum__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: I know that it's not generalized solution, in my project i am also using armadillo library over my own classes/structures. But thank you very much for every remark you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to get the return value from a function that's run in a thread. So, instead of trying to do that, pass a reference to where you want to hold the result. That means changing `sum_array_line` to take a reference:

```
void sum_array_line ( double* arr_line, unsigned int ncols,
    std::reference_wrapper<double> res){
    double s = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ncols; i++){
        s += arr_line[i];
    }
    res = s;
};
```

and changing your inner loop to pass the variable for the result:

```
double results[NUM_T];
for (unsigned j = 0; j < NUM_T; ++j) {
    t[j] = thread(sum_array_line, mtrx.mtrx[i], mtrx.cols, std::ref(results[j]));
    ++i;
}
```

and, as you join each thread, add its result to the running total:

```
for (unsigned j = 0; j < NUM_T; ++j) {
    t[j].join();
    sum += results[j];
}
```

Comment: Dont you need std::ref when passing by reference to a thread?

Comment: @BillHarper - yup. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thank you for providing new solution but this way every result from resutls[j] returns value such as "3.114606e-317".

Comment: I just edited std::reference_wrapper<double> res to pointer only double& res  and it works. But i have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

When I do upgrade of the functions I am using to do the summation with 4 threads. For matrix 20 000 x 20 000 the time needed to calculate the sum is 0.6 sec for single thread accessing elements one by one (2 for cycles) and 1.0 sec for parallel computation with 4 threads. I don't get. Should not be the multithread solution faster?